# How to replace NaT in pandas dataframe with a date using information from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, nan

noob here.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| start | end | start_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaT | NaT | 2020 |
| NaT | NaT | 2021 |

and I want to fill in the NaT's with the first and last day of the year listed in the start_year column. So it would look like this:

| start | end | start_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 | 2020 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 2021 |

I tried to fill in the NaTs in the 'end' column like this:

```
df2.loc[df2['start'].isnull() 
                & df2['end'].isnull()
                & df2['start_year'].notnull()
       , "end"] = dt.date(df2["start_year"], 12, 31)
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

When I look at just the start year column it says this:

```
Name: start_year, Length: 4213, dtype: int64
```

I also tried using

```
df2["start_year"].values
```

but that didn't help.

Apologies if I'm just being an idiot. I searched around on here and google but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both columns start and end, keep the value if filled else fill it with first day (resp last day) of year

```
 df['start'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['start'] if pd.notna(x['start']) else pd.to_datetime(datetime(x['start_year'], 1, 1), format='%y-%m-%d'), axis = 1)
 df['end'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['end'] if pd.notna(x['end']) else pd.to_datetime(datetime(x['start_year'], 12, 31), format='%y-%m-%d'), axis = 1)
```

Comment: This looks promising. For the data I'm working with it's important that I only change the start and end dates where they are both null and the start_date is not null.

Is that possible with this syntax you've shared?

Comment: Absolutely !  Indeed, with this syntax you replace the value only in the case where it is null (x['start'] is not modified unless pd.notna(x['start']) is False which means x is null).

Comment: Ok I had a go and this is what I did:

'df2['start'] = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime(x['start_year'], 1, 1), format='%y-%m-%d') if pd.isna(x['start']) & pd.isna(x['end']) & pd.notna(x['start_year']) else x['start'], axis = 1)'

Does this look right? Also it's coming out as a timestamp. I tried adding '.dt.date' at the end but that errored.

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#if necessary
#df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
#df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

#replace missing values by Year - first day and last day
df['start'] = df['start'].fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['start_year'],format='%Y'))
df['end'] = (df['end'].fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['start_year'].add(1), format='%Y') 
                              - pd.Timedelta('1 day')))

print (df)
       start        end  start_year
0 2020-01-01 2020-12-31        2020
1 2021-01-01 2021-12-31        2021
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['start_year'].apply(pd.Period).dt.to_timestamp('A')
```

output:

```
0   2020-12-31
1   2021-12-31
Name: start_year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: it looks like all values ​​are not nat. This also replaces non-nat values.

Comment: start_year column don have nat