Creating a new dataframe with calculations from a base dataframe where the indexes are independent. Working code, but iterrows inside of a for loop
The dataset I am looking is for animals that have entered my local animal shelter.  The fields I am interested in are the intake_date and the outcome_date which are when the animal entered the shelter and when it left.
I want to be able to plot the total number of animals in residence (i.e. animals that spent the night at a shelter) vs the date.  The logic that I have is:

if the outcome date is null then that record should count for every date from the intake date to present date
else the record should count for every day from the intake date until the day before the outcome date.

I have some working code, but I want to speed it up since I essentially doing 90 million iterations.
Here is the code I have:
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime


def fetch_data():
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Etharialle/shelter-streamlit/main/datasets/asio.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(url, on_bad_lines='skip').replace("'", "", regex=True)
    return df


df = fetch_data()
# Ensure 'Intake Date' is a datetime type
df_open_cases["Intake Date"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_open_cases["Intake Date"])
df_open_cases["Outcome Date"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_open_cases["Outcome Date"])

# Animals in Residence by Date
start_date = df_open_cases["Intake Date"].min()
end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
date_list = {}

while start_date <= end_date:
    loop_date = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    date_list[loop_date] = 0
    start_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

for k, v, in date_list.items():
    for index, rows in df_open_cases.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(rows['Outcome Date']) and rows["Intake Date"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') <= k:
            date_list[k] += 1
        elif rows["Intake Date"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') <= k and rows['Outcome Date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') > k:
            date_list[k] += 1
        else:
            pass
df_dates = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    date_list, orient='index', columns=['Animals in Residence'])

This code does what I want it to, but there are 25000+ records spanning over 10 years.  Which means I am running the if/elif/else 90+ million times.  It took my laptop a few hours to run.  I'm not sure how/if I can vectorize this.  The only way I can think of shortening the loop count is to filter the data frame for iterrows like df_open_cases[df_open_cases.intake_date >= k].iterrows
example of the data set:
    intake_date Outcome Date
27312   2024-04-04  NaT
27313   2024-04-04  NaT
27330   2024-04-04  NaT
27331   2024-04-04  NaT
27332   2024-04-04  NaT
27315   2024-04-04  NaT
27316   2024-04-03  NaT
27317   2024-04-03  NaT
27318   2024-04-03  2024-04-03
27319   2024-04-03  2024-04-03
27320   2024-04-03  2024-04-03
27321   2024-04-03  NaT
27322   2024-04-03  NaT
27323   2024-03-28  NaT
27324   2024-03-28  2024-04-03
27325   2024-03-28  NaT
27326   2024-03-28  2024-04-03
27327   2024-03-28  NaT
27328   2024-04-03  NaT
27329   2024-04-03  2024-04-04
27493   2024-04-03  NaT
27494   2024-04-03  NaT
27300   2024-04-02  NaT
27495   2024-04-02  NaT
27496   2024-04-02  NaT


Does this help? How can I iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title. It's important to be specific and concise, so for example, you can remove the stuff about impound_number and animal_id, which your code never uses. For the title, make it clear that you have working code but you're looking to speed it up. You can [edit].

Ideally the question would include some example data, which you could create by using seeded random values; see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. And it should be smaller; like, we shouldn't need to spend more than a few minutes running our own possible solutions.

One thing you could do right away is not use strftime.

added some of the rows from the dataframe so it can be seen.  The first link I have gone through which is what led me to ask here.  I'm basically creating a new table that is independent of the first table I'm not doing something that could in a vectorized approach as far as I can see.

Updating my loop so the iterrows only uses the from the current iteration of the for loop forward speeds it up significantly, but it still takes 20+ minutes to run since the data set is so large.
I'm now just trying to figure out if there is a better way than iterrows for this scenario.

What makes you think it can't be vectorized? rows["Intake Date"] <= k can be vectorized as df["Intake Date"] <= k, so I think you can extrapolate from there, right?

Does this answer your question? Create a new dataframe counting of all the dates between two dates in another dataframe

Adjusting your case for the suggested duplicate's answers to work: use df["Outcome Date"].fillna(pd.Timestamp.today().floor('D')) to fill up NaN with today's date. The duplicate is also a decent example for future reference: narrow down your Q to what is really the issue and provide a [mre], including the expected output.

Thanks @wjandrea for the help.  I was thinking about my problem the wrong way.  This last comment helped a lot:

What makes you think it can't be vectorized? rows["Intake Date"] <= k can be vectorized as df["Intake Date"] <= k, so I think you can extrapolate from there, right? –
wjandrea

The original loop:
for k, v, in date_list.items():
    for index, rows in df_open_cases.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(rows['Outcome Date']) and rows["Intake Date"] <= k:
            date_list[k] += 1
        elif rows["Intake Date"] <= k and rows['Outcome Date'] > k:
            date_list[k] += 1
        else:
            pass

I was increasing the count in my dictionary by one for each match use if statements.  Instead a better way would be to sum all rows for which the conditions I am looking for are met such as:
for k, v, in date_list.items():
    date_list[k] = ((pd.isnull(df_open_cases['Outcome Date']) &
                    (df_open_cases["Intake Date"] <= k)) |
                    ((df_open_cases["Intake Date"] <= k) &
                    (df_open_cases['Outcome Date'] > k))).sum()

I'm still not sure I understand vectorization 100%, but this definitely helped.  My run time when from hours to one second.

I'm not sure how to replicate NaT but please see this potential option.
In the step where NaT is replaced by 9999-12-31, this syntax may be more relevant than df.loc How to replace NaT in pandas dataframe with a date using information from other columns
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some data for testing
start_date = datetime.date(2023, 4, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2024, 4, 15)

dates = []
for i in range(380):
    dates += [[
        start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i), 
        start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 2) 
        if i%2 == 0
        else start_date + datetime.timedelta(days= i + 3)
        if i % 3 == 0 
        else start_date + datetime.timedelta(days= i + 5)
        if i % 5 == 0                
        else start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 7)
        if i % 7 == 0 
        else " "]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns = ["Intake_date", "Outcome_Date"])

# replace non valid date with a future date eg 9999-12-31 please see alternative at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346808/how-to-replace-nat-in-pandas-dataframe-with-a-date-using-information-from-other
df.loc[df["Outcome_Date"] == " ", "Outcome_Date"] = datetime.date(9999,12,31)

# create list to append date and count to
l1 = []
for d1 in df["Intake_date"].unique():
    c1 = len(df[(df["Intake_date"] <= d1) & (d1 <= df["Outcome_Date"])])
    l1 += [[d1, c1]]
    
# convert list to dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns = ["Date", "Count"])
df1

